# How to use variables in subprocess executing multiple commands in single session using python

Tags: python, variables, static, double-quotes

I want to run the multiple shell commands using subprocess in python. The commands contains variables as well.

Below is the code that I have tried, But it is not working.

```
import subprocess
fdr = "build"
dir = "temp"
subprocess.call("cd "+fdr+";mkdir "+dir+";cd "+dir+";pwd", shell=True)
```

`fdr, dir` are the variables.
how can I do this?

Comment: you have fdr instead of fldr. But what error it returns if it is not working?

Comment: @Bulva - Its my mistake.. Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem with `&&`. Try this:

```
import subprocess
fdr = "build"
dir = "temp"
subprocess.call("cd "+fdr+" && mkdir "+dir+" && cd "+dir+" && pwd", shell=True)
```

The `&&` in bash calls other command only if the first was successful. It works on my machine (unfortunately I have only Windows cmd right now so I've made some changes for my version but It should works the same).